# How to find the dimensions of context.fillText(text, x, y)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am drawing text on a canvas and was wondering how I can get the dimensions of the text to be drawn.

Height should be simple enough.

My only thought is that to use a monospace font, and calculate the length from the number of characters. Is there a better way to do this yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read this [drawing text using canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/drawing_text_using_a_canvas) documentation?
Especially from the [methods section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/drawing_text_using_a_canvas#section_3);
The [measureText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/drawing_text_using_a_canvas#section_7) method seems to do what you ask.

Although there is no example at the documentation I'm guessing the use is something like:

```
var text = 'this is my text';
var text_ctx = ctx.measureText(text);
var text_width = text_ctx.width;
```

Comment: You actually need text_width.width, as `measureText` returns an object

Comment: Thanks for the correction @andynormancx, in fact I said "I'm guessing" because I never used or tested it and I from the documentation it was not possible to tell exactly how to do it. Although, it was a step in the right direction.